mockResolvedValue is not a function: How are we able to unit-test TSOA rest endpoints with jest?
I am trying to run a simple unit-test for one of my REST endpoints.
However, I am not able to successfully mock the TopicEntity.findAll function.
With the following:
import request from 'supertest';
import { app } from '../../main.js';

import { jest } from '@jest/globals';
import { TopicEntity } from '../../db/entity/TopicEntity.js';

jest.mock('../../db/entity/TopicEntity.js');

describe('TopicController', () => {
  describe('GET /topics', () => {
    it('should return a list of topics', async () => {
      // Given
      const mockTopics = [
        { id: 1, name: 'JavaScript' },
        { id: 2, name: 'TypeScript' },
      ];
      (TopicEntity.findAll as jest.Mock).mockResolvedValue(mockTopics as never);

      // when
      const response = await request(app).get('/api/topics');

      // then
      expect(response.status).toBe(200);
      expect(response.body).toEqual(mockTopics);
    });
  });
});

I am receiving
TopicEntity.findAll.mockResolvedValue is not a function
TypeError: TopicEntity.findAll.mockResolvedValue is not a function

I have also tried to use the module factory for mockking the object:
jest.mock('../../db/entity/TopicEntity.js', () => {
  return {
    TopicEntity: {
      findAll: jest.fn(),
    },
  };
});

But I get the same result.
How can I successfully mock this function?

Can you show the code of TopicEntity.js?

Are you using ESM? If so read https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules

It turns out that static methods must be mocked like the following:
describe(TopicController.name, () => {
  describe('GET /topics', () => {
    it('should return a list of topics', async () => {
      // given
      const mockTopics: Topic[] = [
        { id: 1, name: 'JavaScript' },
        { id: 2, name: 'TypeScript' },
      ];

      TopicEntity.findAll = jest.fn<() => Promise<Topic[]>>().mockResolvedValue(mockTopics) as any;

      // when
      const response = await request(app).get('/api/topics');

      // then
      expect(response.status).toBe(200);
      expect(response.body).toEqual(mockTopics);
    });
  });
});

